# In unserer WG ist es schwierig mit dem Essen

Tags: meaning

In `Cafe in Berlin` on chapter two I have below sentence.

> In unserer WG ist es schwierig mit dem Essen.

What's the meaning of this?(WG is not there in dictionary)

Comment: WG = Wohngemeinschaft

Comment: One should add, nobody uses *Wohngemeinschaft*, all people say *Weegee*.

Comment: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/WG

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/WG, https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wohngemeinschaft

Comment: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/WG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*WG* is short for *Wohngemeinschaft* (*shared apartment*).

The abbreviation is used almost exclusively